# $event->performAction = false; doesn't stop action

Tags: plugin-development, activation

I've got a plugin which creates an entry on user activation. I'm trying to extend the plugin so that after public registration the account is not activated (i.e., force an Admin to activate the account).

According to the documentation I'd expect this code block to stop activation:

```
public function init() {
    craft()->on('users.beforeActivateUser', function(Event $event){
        // stop the user from being able to activate their account. Forces admins to do so.
        //if($event->params['user']->isInGroup('artists')){
            $event->performAction = false;
        //}
    });
}
```

But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Full plugin code here: https://gist.github.com/MattWilcox/1549fb9d5787288b3b84

Comment: Looks O.K. to me and can't reproduce locally. If you have xDebug installed, throw a breakpoint on `$event->performAction = false` and step through it to see what's happening.

Comment: I don't have that installed :/

Can I confirm I'm understanding what it should do correctly? It is creating the user after registration as Active (green) but with the code above it *does* stop the plugin's 'onActivateUser' block from running (and so no entry is created for the new user).

I expected it to not have a green active user immediately on registration due to that code above. If I set email validation as required, the user remains pending (orange). That's what I want (but without the email being required).

Comment: Yeah... kinda sounds like a bug. Will do some testing and update here with the results.

Comment: Thanks Brad, let me know if you'd like the file/database dump. Sorry I can't help track this down further; my PHP-foo is old and weak.

Comment: Per [Brad's comment](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/7125/45), this is a bug and has been fixed for the next release. Closing as a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Craft that's been fixed for the next ([post 2.3.2629](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2629)) release.